# Loop de Requisições no useEffect

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou fazendo um post na minha API e quero atualizar a minha lista de livros sempre que eu criar um novo livro.
O meu Post está funcionando, porém quando eu adiciono a minha "lista" dentro do [lista] no use useEffects um Loop é iniciado e a aplicação não para de gerar requisições.
A minha lista é atualizada, mas o Loop não termina.

Gostaria de saber o motivo disso e uma forma de resolver.
Obrigado!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "../../services/api";

function ListaLivros() {

    const [lista, setLivros] = useState([])

    const novo_livro = {
        nome: "Toquinho Book",
        valor: 120,
        descricao: "A Saga de um Desenvolvedor Desesperado",
        produto: "livro"
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get("/lista_livros").then(({ data }) => {
            setLivros(data);
            console.log(data);
        })
    }, [lista]);



    function addLivro() {
        api.post("/lista_livros", novo_livro)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <section>
                <div className="form ">
                    <input type="text" className="input" />
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => addLivro()}>Adicionar Um Novo Livro</button>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead className="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Id</th>
                            <th scope="col">Nome do Livro</th>
                            <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                            <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
                            <th scope="col">Produto</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {
                        lista?.map((lista) => (
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th key={lista.id}>{lista.id}</th>
                                    <td>{lista.nome}</td>
                                    <td>{lista.valor}</td>
                                    <td>{lista.descricao}</td>
                                    <td>{lista.produto}</td>
                                    <td><button className="btn btn-warning">Editar</button></td>
                                    <td><button className="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button></td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        ))
                    }
                </table>
            </section>
        </>
    );

};

export default ListaLivros;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema esta na lista de dependências do seu `useEffect`, veja que você passa `lista` no `array` de dependências, e internamente você atualiza esse estado após a requisição ser completa, fazendo isso você altera o valor de `lista` e o `useEffect` entra em loop. No geral basta você remover o lista das dependências do `useEffect`.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        api.get("/lista_livros").then(({ data }) => {
            setLivros(data);
            console.log(data);
        })
    }, []);
```

Importante observar que no caso de objetos, `arrays` e funções o react não irá comparar cada item ou atributo, ele irá apenas comparar a referência.

---

Para Adicionar um novo item ao array, basta atualizar o estado adicionando o novo item.

```
  function addLivro() {
        api.post("/lista_livros", novo_livro)
           .then(() => setLivros(prevValue => [...prevValue, novo_livro]))
    }
```

No exemplo acima o novo item será adicionado somente após a requisição ser concluida com sucesso.

[Javascript – atribuição por referência x atribuição por valor](https://odesenvolvedor.com.br/javascript-atribuicao-por-referencia-x-atribuicao-por-valor.html)

[Usando Effect Hook (Hook de Efeito)](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Entendi, porém se eu remover o lista do array eu não consigo atualizar a minha lista.    Por favor, como faço para atualizar a minha lista sempre que eu adicionar um novo item?

Comment: Acredito que você possa atualizar o estado adicionando o novo item, vou adicionar um exemplo na resposta.

Comment: Funcionou, consigo fazer a atualização. Porém ocorre um bug, que criar um novo livro ele cria o livro porém não exibe o ID.

Comment: O ideal seria você pegar a resposta da sua API pra poder atualizar o estado, no geral seria alterar o `then` para algo assim `.then((response) => setLivros(prevValue => [...prevValue, response]))`. porém eu não sei ao certo qual o tipo de retorno poderia variar muito então acabei preferindo usar o `novo_livro` como exemplo.